# Vectorization : How do I avoid two for-loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, vectorization

Thru this post, I am looking for inputs to vectorize my python code which is currently using two for-loops. I want to avoid the usage of for-loops for performance reasons. My current working python code is shown below.

what does the code do?
I have an input dataframe with column c1 that has 4 rows with 10's and three rows with 20's. Column c2 is another column with some random numbers.

Expected output: I have a window size of 2. so, for every 2 rows where c1 = 10 or c1=20, i have to compute mean of corresponding column c2. I have the input and expected output screenshots attached.

At the moment, I am achieving this using two for loops.

Input dataframe screenshot: [input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srB4W.png)
Expected output screenshot: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rtAX.png)

My current Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'c1':10, 'c2':10},{'c1':10,'c2':20},{'c1':10,'c2':30},{'c1':10,'c2':40},
       {'c1':20,'c2':50},{'c1':20,'c2':60},{'c1':20,'c2':70}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # df = Input
df.head()
 
window = 2
allDF = pd.DataFrame()
records = df['c1'].unique()

for x in records:
    intervalsDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','meanc2'])
    df2 = df.loc[df['c1'] == x]
    for i in range(0, len(df2), window):
        intervalIndex = len(intervalsDF)
        interval = df2[i:i+window]
        c1 = list(interval['c1'])[0]
        meanc2 = interval['c2'].mean()
        intervalSummary = [c1,meanc2]
        intervalsDF.loc[intervalIndex] = intervalSummary
    allDF = allDF.append(intervalsDF) # allDF is the expected output

allDF.head()
```

Comment: The relation between input and output dataframes are not obvious.

Comment: I have an input dataframe with column c1 has 4 rows of 10's and three rows of 20's. Column c2 is just another column.  Expected output: I have a window size of 2. so, for every 2 rows where c1 = 10 or c1=20, i have to compute mean of corresponding column c2. I have the input and expected output screenshots attached.

Comment: I see. Check the reply and mark it as solving your issue if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a shorter, simpler way to perform the transformation.  But here's an approach that avoids loops.

```
# create the data frame, as per the original post
data = [{'c1':10, 'c2':10},
        {'c1':10,'c2':20},
        {'c1':10,'c2':30},
        {'c1':10,'c2':40},
        {'c1':20,'c2':50},
        {'c1':20,'c2':60},
        {'c1':20,'c2':70}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # df = Input

# 1. convert the index to an ordinary column
df = df.reset_index()

# 2. 'helper' is a column that counts 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 
#     and re-starts for each c1
df['helper'] = df['index'] - df.groupby('c1')['index'].transform(min)

# 3. integer division on 'helper', to get 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... 
# (identify non-overlapping pairs)
df['helper'] //= 2

# 4. now convert 'index' from ordinary column back to an Index
df = df.set_index('index')

# 5. compute the mean of c2 for value of 'c1' and each pair of observations
df = df.groupby(['c1', 'helper'])['c2'].mean()

# 6. re-order 'helper' and 'c1' to match order in output
df.index = df.index.swaplevel()

print(df)

helper  c1
0       10    15
1       10    35
0       20    55
1       20    70
Name: c2, dtype: int64
```